# Nuxt Content + Vuetify components = how to remove block of imports in template page which will render markdown content

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt-content

In my "personal page" project I'm using NuxtJS, with it's `@nuxt/content` module for content and Vuetify UI framework.

Recently found a problem: Vuetify component inside markdown files are not rendered when generating static site, but rendered correctly when running project in development mode. I've checked for issues in [@nuxt/content](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+vuetify) about this problem and found 2 issues: [#221](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/221) and [#700](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/700)

Mainly discussion was inside [issue #221](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/221#issuecomment-789113182).

Shortly as I understand from issue:
Vuetify loader doesn't check content of markdown files, that's why while running `nuxt generate` Vuetify components(that may be used in any component without import) are not rendered while used inside markdown files.
At `nuxt dev` mode Vuetify component are rendered correctly because treeshake is disabled for development mode

Inside markdown file I used only one component - [`<v-alert>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/), so finaly solution was next:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { VAlert } from 'vuetify/lib'
Vue.component('VAlert', VAlert)
```

I need to use this code at page which will display markdown files content. With it `nuxt generate` result is what I want - Vuetify component successfully rendered if used inside markdown file.

But this code also bring one problem: if I running it with `nuxt dev` I'm getting error `Unexpected token 'export'` when I visit page that displays markdown with Vuetify components.

[image]

Finally the question is: How to remove these imports from page with template for showing markdown content? Probably something like "conditional import" (make these imports executed only when running `nuxt generate`) or anything else?

Of course I can comment/uncomment each time I run project in development mode, but I'm not sure it's the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrapped each vuetify component, I've used in markdown, in my own version of it.

```
// my-markdown-alert.vue
<template>
  <v-alert v-bind="$attrs"><slot></slot></v-alert>
</template>
```

btw. the link `a href="/my-file.zip"` or its markdown counterpart `[Link](/my-file.zip)`, if used for downloading a file from the same page, throws 404 page not found, in my nuxt + vuetify. After wrapping it in `my-markdown-link`, it works again.

```
<a v-bind="$attrs"><slot></slot></a>
```

The above provides only the one way binding. If you need to watch for events from the wrapper, please refer to the following answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824575

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It removes unnecessary block of imports at page template and both `nuxt generate` and `nuxt dev` now works fine.
But I guess I need to edit my question before marking your answer as solution.